# How to query MongoDB with regex?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

humans.json

```
{
    "_id": "22YAE7bEXdST9MyrZ",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2016-11-22T15:09:25.968Z"
    },
    "abilities": {
        "power": {
            "mana":78,
            "chakra":0
            "energy":60
        }
    },
    "emails": [
        {
            "address": "Rob6@rob.com",
            "working": false
        }
    ],
    "roles": [
        "killing":true
    ]
}
```

So I want to get only the `emails.address` with the first character in uppercase.

Comment: Do you want the documents where the email address is in uppercase or do you want only the email address field & project the email addresses with the first letter in capital?

Comment: Hi LisaN, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SubhashreePradhan I want to get all the documents that got an email in uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use regex like javascript:

```
db.humans.find({'emails.address': /^[A-Z]/})
```

If you have many emails in your array, but only want to returned matched email (start with upper case letter), you can use additional projection:

```
db.humans.find({'emails.address': /^[A-Z]/}, {emails: {$elemMatch: {'address': /^[A-Z]/}}})
```

Comment: Thank you sir for you comment, i tried this in mlab {
   'emails.address': /^[A-Z]/
}

 Got a json validator error

Comment: I believe you're doing something wrong. Here is my local result: [image link](https://imgur.com/a/fScTjhq)